# Which delete is find using?

Tags: macos

I ask because I was looking at the maintenance scripts OS X runs (/private/etc/periodic/daily/) and, for example, the one that cleans out old tmp files (110.clean-tmps) uses the following 2 lines to run the deletion:

```
find -dx . -fstype local -type f $args -delete $print
find -dx . -fstype local ! -name . -type d $dargs -delete $print
```

There are both `rm` and `srm` utilities in OS X, but how would I know which one `find` was using, or if it was using its own? (or if I could force it to use one or the other). Since the maintenance scripts cover things like tmp files, log files and the like, it seems a possible avenue for data leakage. I also occasionally see scripts using the `find -delete` option - how secure is it? `man find` told me nothing about it beyond its usage.

This may apply to other BSD's too (the scripts have comments about FreeBSD) but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Migrating.

Comment: Find uses the unlink system call and does not attempt to overwrite the file before deletion.

Comment: @fd0: It seems to me that your comment provides exactly the information the OP is seeking. Consider reposting it as an an answer.

Comment: Preferably with a source or reference